# Required Formula in Excel

Tags: formula

I am looking for a formula to search a text in Column A and return column B, C & D. I tried Xkookup, but it wont work. I have tons of data to sort.

[image]

I required a formula for above, thanks and regards

Comment: vlookup() index() with match() can all work. Provide some data to test. Giving an image and expecting us to type data for you is a good way to not get an answer.

Comment: Please read: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) says: "Introduce the problem before you post any code".  You forgot to post your code ....    (What  did you try to solve this, and why did that fail ?)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue really is here:

1. `XLOOKUP` works great at it, and "natively" (no "tricks").
2. Therefore (and really), `INDEX/MATCH` does it too, and just as natively as `XLOOKUP`.
3. `VLOOKUP` does it nicely as well, though a small, uncommon to most folks' experience, "trick" is used.

So... is the problem just not knowing the trick? I guess that if so, then it might not leap out at one how to use the first two either (maybe).

I'll show that in a moment. The other though revolves around how the items in column A do not appear only once. So maybe you don't want a lookup's standard "find the first one and quit" approach... perhaps you want to find all ROWS with the value as well as all columns. In which case, none of the above will work as Excel generally cannot provide rows AND columns in any of their lookup methods. Although, one can actually achive it with a lot of trickiness using `INDEX/MATCH` because one puts a piece of the trickiness in the `MATCH` half and a piece in the `INDEX` half rather than both pieces in a single function (which is why the trickiness won't work in `XLOOKUP`:  it's a single function so no splitting the trickiness).

However, `FILTER` is made for that precise purpose, returning a 2-D result and would do it for you very nicely. Its output can also be fed into other functions to (for example) provide a single row output that, say, sums all the rows it found.

So exactly what you need is a big question here. And who knows, it could be something else entirely.

So, for `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,A2:D10,  {2,3,4},  FALSE)
```

Notice the parameter I separated with spaces? The column-to-return parameter (third one)? It is not a simple digit, like `2` but rather an `array constant` as Excel likes to call it. The function will return values from all three of the listed columns, in the order their column numbers appear. So you could reverse them by using `{4,3,2}` and could have one returned multiple times (`{2,3,2,2,2,4}` for example). And any function that results in a similar array would be fine as well, so `SEQUENCE(1,3,2,1)` would work nicely. That means you can use calculations to fill in the values for said function and dynamically generate the function's output rather than hardcode (type) it in. (You cannot get a calculation you type inside an array constant to work, not even using `INDIRECT`... if it's an array constant, Excel regards it permanently as fixed textual material.)

`XLOOKUP` does this "natively" since its third parameter can be a multi-column range and a value from each column in that range will be part of its output. No trickiness, you just list the range. So:

```
=XLOOKUP(F2,A2:A10,  B2:D10)
```

B2:D10 has three columns, so the result will be a row that has three columns of values.

Moving on to you actually wanting a 2-D array (rows AND columns returned, not just a single row or a single column returned). `FILTER` would work like this:

```
=FILTER(B2:D10,  A2:A10=F2)
```

For it, you specify the range that `XLOOKUP` would have used first, then a test it will apply to each row in whatever column you want to test. The column you are looking in is not desired in your output so be careful to not include it in that first range (so NOT A2:D10). Only include the range holding things you actually want returned by the function.

Then DO use the lookup column in your test. In this case, you are testing to see if each of the values in it match your lookup value, or do not match. "Under the hood" Excel is making an array constant of 1's and 0's (TRUE and FALSE values to Excel) and will return corresponding rows from the first parameter range for any that match (return a 1).

In this case, "Fabric" appears twice so two rows would appear in your results.

And if you want to further process that info, just feed it to an appropriate function or formula. `SUM` for example. Craft its form to match what you need done. For instance, summing all six returned values for "Fabric" into a single number would be crafted differently than summing each column of returned values for three resulting numbers.

Lastly, always remember that you can use an array constant (one you type in by hand or one you generate somehow) for MANY functions. It can be a very useful thing to remember.